# Birt - Crosstab getting clipped on PDF

Tags: birt

My crosstab looks fine in the web viewer but when I export to PDF it's clipping it like showin in the image.  It's also making the columns much wider than they need to be.  (The web version isn't doing that.)

Does anyone know how to fix it?  I tried searching for an answer and didn't see anything.[image]

Comment: What version of BIRT? Also does this report get generated as both HTML and as PDF or only PDF?

Comment: I think the designer is on 3.71?  And the runtime on my server is 3.7.2?  Yes, the report needs to be viewable as HTML on the web viewer and PDF generated from the console.

Comment: Another angle to attack this problem is why are the detail cells being made so wide on the PDF?  In the web version they are barely wider than the numbers (which is what I'd want).  So even if it stops the clipping to allow overflow or change the page width, the report might get unwieldedly wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have restricted the width/height of your report 
goto Master Page then click on the general settings and there you find the type drop-down choose Custom.
Through this custom options you can give your own height/width of your report and too in the report layout.By doing this you can expand your report width

NOTE: The master page width should equal to the width of your layout.

Comment: I'll give this a try, but see my third comment I just added to the question.  I'd probably have to set a crazy page width to make this approach work because the PDF is making the cells so wide.

Comment: Yes! I agree there will be a space alignment while exporting PDF and too printing the report.This is a major drawback  in BIRT.I too face the same problem what you mentioned but i define the cells width individually so that the PDF and Printing will be more compact.

Comment: Ok, dumb question.  How do I define the cells' widths for a cross tab?  I'm not seeing that option anywhere.

Comment: By clicking CROSS TAB cells you will find the width and height options in the property window's-->General attributes.
NOTE:DON'T click on the dataset which is in the crosstab

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the parameters you're passing to your RenderTask it is hard to tell exactly, so I'm going to guess that you have `PAGE_OVERFLOW` set to `CLIP_CONTENT` rather than `FIT_TO_PAGE_SIZE`.

A note of caution though. [This discussion on the Eclipse forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/815848/) mentions that page-break interval settings might override the page size render options. Note that the OP on the linked discussion was having a problem with the PDF exported from the HTML viewer.

EDIT: according to the docs inside `genReport.sh` you are able to pass parameters on the command line (`-p pageOverflow=FIT_TO_PAGE_SIZE`) or you can create a parameter file (`-F params.txt`)

It is unclear to me whether you can pass the constant (`FIT_TO_PAGE_SIZE`) or must pass its expected value (`2`), so you might have to try both.

Comment: So how would I see what parameters I'm passing to the rendertask?  (What is the RenderTask?)

Comment: I'm using the command line to generate the PDF e.g., ./genReport.sh -m runrender -f PDF -o /tmp/test.pdf my_report.rptdesign

Comment: The *render task* is the part of the report engine pipeline that turns the data (extracted by the run task) into an output (pdf). In your example command just above, you are issuing a call to `genReport.sh` with direction for a `runrender` task. One might use `run` and `render` separately for some imaginitive report caching.

Comment: Update, this didn't work with 2 nor with FIT_TO_PAGE_SIZE.  It seemed to have no effect:  `genReport.sh -m runrender -f PDF -p pageOverflow=FIT_TO_PAGE_SIZE -o /tmp/tmpbAETGC.pdf cpu.rptdesign`